# Clean uninstall of AU Lab?

Tags: applications, audio, xcode, music

long long ago through updates or whatever apples AU Lab stopped working on my MacBook Pro. Every attempt to reinstall, even latest version didn't bring it back to live. Currently a new attempt is made with the 2.4 version on Yosemite 10.3. But after selecting a configuration the same as ever: No document window is opening. May be there are old settings hidden in special places? So I need to know how to TOTALLY delete any traces of the app from my computer to start a new attempt. Any infos desperately appriciated!! THX.

Comment: If you want to link to AU Lab or describe where the files exist, someone might have instructions on how to clean install or tailor the Apple Migration script so you  an do a clean install of OS X and then skip importing that one problematic lab.

Comment: A clean install of OSX is not a option, too much specials... :-) I just need to know where AU Lab stores data (plists, etc.) so I can delete old versions... AU Lab starts normally but it doesn't create OR display any documents any more - no matter what I try...

Comment: heh heh - I hate being in the situation where I can't reinstall the OS. Postponing the pain is sometimes needed, but never fun. I hope someone knows what's up and can help specifically...

Comment: Sure, you're right. And ok, I can, too. But its expensive (time) and so I 1st try to find another solution. If nobody has the needed infos, I'll finally have no other chance: Clean install OS or give up having a system-wide EQ...

Comment: Wow!! Problem solved!! Found a little program, AppCleaner. It showed dependencies (plist and a subfolder in "Library"). After deleting these two items and restarting the MacBook, everything is fine now and the document window in AU Lab opens again!! I'm happy :-)